# MySQL query to find out matching record

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 3 tables: 
1) customers 2)rentals 3) actors.

I want the result like this: rental tables contains films rented by customers

We will get the result from this query:

```
SELECT customers.first_name,customers.last_name
FROM customers LEFT JOIN
     rentals
     ON customers.customer_id = rentals.customer_id
```

and what I want is from this result: I have to find out the customers who have same first name and last name in the actors table.

I have done a query to find the matching result between the customers table and the actors table using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.first_name,customers.last_name
FROM customers JOIN
     actors
     ON customers.first_name LIKE CONCAT('%',actors.first_name,'%') AND customers.last_name LIKE CONCAT('%',actors.last_name,'%')
```

Please help me to find out using one query.

I tried like this, but I don't know if it is accurate:

```
 SELECT customers.first_name
      , customers.last_name 
   FROM customers 
   JOIN actors 
     ON customers.first_name LIKE CONCAT('%',actors.first_name,'%') 
    AND customers.last_name LIKE CONCAT('%',actors.last_name,'%') 
  WHERE customers.customer_id IN (SELECT rentals.customer_id FROM rentals)
```

Comment: Why are you using `like` if you want the same name?

Comment: @GordonLinoff without LIKE possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the customers' first name and last **same** (rather than within the same patterns) with actors' first name and last name, respectively, `=` is enough.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.first_name,customers.last_name
FROM customers 
JOIN actors 
ON customers.first_name = actors.first_name AND customers.last_name = actors.last_name  
WHERE customers.customer_id IN (SELECT rentals.customer_id FROM rentals)
```

Comment: i have one doubt, that matching name list must be find from the join result of customers table with rental table,so this query is perfect?

Comment: I think this could work. If possible, please add sample data that we may further test whether the query fully works.

Comment: its giving data. but for confirming i asked